# Video recording with GPUImage Android

Tags: android, video-capture, gpuimage, video-recording

I want to use **GPUImage Android** to process video in real time. I see example that creating pictures with different filters but I didnt find any example of recording video with filters. Is this possible with GPUImage Android?

Answer (score 2):

android-gpuimage library does not support video recording but you can try using the android-gpuimage-videorecording library. It is a fork of the gpu-image for android that provides also the video recording functionality

[android-gpuimage-videorecording](https://github.com/westbrett/android-gpuimage-videorecording)

see the GPUImageMovieWriter class

It should point you in the right direction for developing your own video writer on top of GPUImage.

The idea is to:

- draw on current screen surface
- switch to encoder input surface and draw previous frame buffer again on it
- switch back to screen surface

other useful links: [EGL surface helper](https://github.com/google/grafika), [Media encoder](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample)

Answer (score 1):

[GPUVideo-android](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android)

I know GPUVideo-android. This library apply video filter on generate an Mp4 and on ExoPlayer video and Video Recording with Camera2.
Android MediaCodec API is used this library.

Let's try camera record , video preview and video generate.